# What type of structure is RewriteEngine?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've used it over and over, but never really considered what RewriteEngine is. I've tried to find an answer in the search engines, but they don't address my specific question:

Is it a function call?
Is it a variable?
Is it a configuration type setting like a PHP.ini setting?

Is the scope the whole .htaccess file. That is, does it terminate when the file is no longer being used?

Comment: This is a very surprising standpoint to say that you did research, but did not find an answer... Actually the documentation of the apache http server has a whole section about those "distributed configuration files", how they are interpreted, what they may contain. And the documentation of all the modules of the apache http server explain in detail what directives are defined. So the answer to your question is: distributed configuration files are _configuration files_ interpreted by the http server if the interpretation is enabled: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: That was a very helpful link for this question. One of my searches took me to a different page on the site, but unfortunately, not the one with the answer.

Taking your answer and looking further, it seems that each line in php.ini is also called a directive. I have mostly heard them referred to as a "setting".

Comment: It seems you confuse the php settings file (typically called `php.ini`) with the directives used in distributed configuration files (often called `.htaccess`) used by the apache http server. Both have nothing to do with each other. The php configuration sets settings inside the php engine. The directives in http server configuration can do various things, since the content of such configuration files is handed over to various modules inside the http server.

Comment: I have found that comparing and contrasting is a great way to learn and put principles into perspective. This methodology works well with my students and clients. 

As an example, the compare and contrast helped me understand the difference between how memory stores variables as compared to functions. My operating systems prof was very good at this methodology.